# How can I get the Current item position in recyclerview after Filtering item using custom SearchView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

when I type & search item name in Custom Search view basically its an Editext which in I am typing searching text, but after searching the item for example banana it properly filter and shows banana item but when I click on that it shows the wrong position toast plz somebody, anybody help me to rid out of this bug

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<AdapterItem> mAdapterList;

TextView Headertv;
LinearLayout SearchView;
EditText editTextSearch;
ImageView ivClearText;

RecyclerView recyclerView;
CustomAdapter adapter;

public String[] fruitnames,

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    createAList();
    buildRecyclerView();

    Headertv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_name_head);
    SearchView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
    editTextSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_search_text);
    ivClearText = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_clear_text);

    editTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            filter(s.toString());
        }
    });

    editTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(searchViewTextWatcher);
    ivClearText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editTextSearch.setText("");
        }
    });
}

public void search_names(View view) {
    editTextSearch.requestFocus();
    editTextSearch.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(editTextSearch, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
    Headertv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    SearchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void Close_Search_View(View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),
            InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);
    editTextSearch.setText("");
    Headertv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    SearchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private void filter(String text) {

    ArrayList<AdapterItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (final AdapterItem item : mAdapterList) {
        if (item.getText1().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
            filteredList.add(item);
        }
    }

    adapter.filterList(filteredList);
}

TextWatcher searchViewTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.toString().trim().length() == 0) {
            ivClearText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            ivClearText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        filter(editable.toString());
    }
};

private void createAList() {

    fruitnames = new String[]{"apple","mango", "cherry","banana","kiwi"};

    mAdapterList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i =0;i<fruitnames .length;i++)
        {
            mAdapterList.add(new AdapterItem( fruitnames[i]));
        }
}


private void buildRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(mAdapterList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new ItemTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new ItemTouchListener.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {

            AdapterItem currentItem = mAdapterList.get(position);

            if (currentItem.getText1().contains(fruitnames[position])) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "name displayed:" + currentItem.getText1() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
        }
    }));

}
}
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.AViewHolder> {
 private ArrayList<AdapterItem> mAdapterList;

public static class AViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mTextView1;

    public AViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);

    }
}

public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<AdapterItem> adapterList) {
    mAdapterList = adapterList;
}

@Override
public AViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recyclerview,
            parent, false);
    return new AViewHolder(v);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AViewHolder holder, int position) {
    AdapterItem currentItem = mAdapterList.get(position);

    holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mAdapterList.size();
}


public void filterList(ArrayList<AdapterItem> filteredList) {
    mAdapterList = filteredList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

**ItemTouchListener.java**

```
public class ItemTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener 
{
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private ClickListener clickListener;

public ItemTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, 
final ClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new 
GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.onLongClick(child, 
     recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (child != null && clickListener != null && 
gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}

public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);

    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}
}
```

Comment: Please be more precise, I don't really understand the problem. 
You filter banana it works fine. But what then ? When you click on that it shows what? 
And what result do you expect?

Comment: when I search for the banana or other fruit & click on that filtered item in recyclerview it shows Apple in Toast means the previous position fruit name in Toast But I want the current filtered  Item fruit name that is banana in toast how can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure of what you trully want but you can try this :

Inside the bindViewHolder in your class adapter, write this :

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


  AdapterItem currentItem = mAdapterList.get(position);

        if (currentItem.getText1().contains(fruitnames[position])) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "name displayed:" + currentItem.getText1() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        }
    });
```

And you remove the `recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener...`

Comment: Please understand my question properly plz bro plz I am not able to get the correct position of item after filtering  that is my problem

Comment: No worries bro, by the way, thanks for your help I have solved that problem

Answer (score 0):

**Added for Loop in Onclick & solved my Problem**

```
   for(int i= 0 ;i< fruitnames.length;i++){
    if (currentItem.getText1().contains(fruitnames[i])) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "name displayed:" + currentItem.getText1() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
    }
```